# How to save URL's to a MYSQL database from an array

Tags: php, mysql, url

What is the best way to save a URL or symbols into a MYSQL database.

I'v seen this being used "{$htmlOutputArray[1]}"
and then else where this "$htmlOutputArray[1]"
and some other places do what i'v done below... but which is the best?

So far I have: (example code)

```
$html = "034251\nhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
$htmlOutputArray = explode("\n", "$html");

$htmlOutput = $htmlOutputArray[0];
$postIDOutput = $htmlOutputArray[1];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
#echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db("dbName", $con);
mysql_query("UPDATE tableName SET PostidINT='$postIDOutput', URLofPostTXT='$htmlOutput' WHERE id='$unID'");
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should look into the dangers of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and how you can prevent it.

Here's both a way you can do this and the safer version.

```
mysql_select_db("dbName", $con);

$sql = sprintf("UPDATE tableName SET PostidINT=%d, URLofPostTXT='%s' WHERE id=%d",
     mysql_real_escape_string($htmlOutputArray[1]), 
     mysql_real_escape_string($htmlOutputArray[0]), 
     mysql_real_escape_string($unID));

mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($con);
```

What [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is doing is preventing unsafe characters from being entered into your database.

What [sprintf()](http://is.php.net/sprintf) is doing is formatting your string, so for example, only numbers will be entered in the PostidINT and id variables.

Answer (score 3):

I'd vote for prepared statements (and mysqli):

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET PostidINT=?, URLofPostTXT=? WHERE id=?");
$statement->bind_param("i", $postIDOutput);
$statement->bind_param("s", $htmlOutput);
$statement->bind_param("i", $unID);
$statement->execute();
```